# Pass component as a prop in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

I got an article showing how to pass a component as a prop, but I could not make it works, can anyone help me on it?

**This is the example I got.**

```
import React from "react";
import Foo from "./components/Foo";
import Bar from "./components/Bar";

const Components = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
};

export default block => {
  // component does exist
  if (typeof Components[block.component] !== "undefined") {
    return React.createElement(Components[block.component], {
      key: block._uid,
      block: block
    });
  }
}
```

**And this is my code**

I have one file called routes.js, that has the state called routes.

```
var routes = [
  {
    path: "/user-profile",
    name: "Quem Somos",
    icon: "FaIdBadge",
    component: UserProfile,
    layout: "/admin"
  }
```

And another component called Sidebar, where I receive routes and need to change the icon based in what is configured at the 'routes' prop.

```
const Components = {
      fa:FaIdBadge
    }

<i>{prop => Components(prop.icon)}</i>
```

But the property with the icon is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close.

[Choosing the Type as Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

```
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  // Correct! JSX type can be a capitalized variable.
  const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
  return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

So more specific to your example

```
// component map in the file for lookup
const components = {
  fa: FaIdBadge,
}

...

  // In the render function
  // fetch the component, i.e. props.icon === 'fa'
  const IconComponent = components[props.icon];

  ...

  <IconComponent />
```

Comment: Thank for you response @Drew, but I was trying to do it and now  I separeted the IconComponent in other file and now I am receiving an error message.

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Once again, Thanks a lot for the response.